# Unify the size of swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, ant, flex4.5

When I compile the same project with ant many times it gives a different sizes for each compilation 
I added the rsl and more option to mxml it works fine ,but the size is still changed

Please any idea to unify the size

Comment: How much variation in size are you seeing?

Comment: if i setting accessible ="false" the variation is in order of 60 octets  if not the variation is in order of 3 octets

Answer (score 1):

This is not really possible, unless you do some, quite involved post-processing. Below is the list of things I know to change the size between compiles, but it may not be exhaustive:

- When you compile pure AS3 project or a project that uses framework:

  1. Resources you embed on variables have their class names generated using the current date in the name.
  2. Flex compiler generates a tag of obscure purpose (can be removed manually, but persists in release builds), which seem to contain a GUID and a compilation time or something similar. It is usually found at the very beginning of the SWF file, somewhere after the rectangle of the SWF dimensions.
- In a project that uses framework:

  1. All code generation is suspect to generating inconsistent names, particularly, all bindings will certainly produce different assembly upon each compile. Styles and some other rarely used metadata will cause this too.
  2. Specifically for spark skins, which come as sources rather then compiled libraries - some of them embed resources in a bad way, so you would probably need to compile them into a library and plug it into a project, removing the sources from the source path.

All in all, if you are using pure AS3 project, your task is difficult, but doable (will require following certain conventions and some post-build script that unzips the SWF, purges the compiler-added extra tag and zips the SWF back. But if it is a SWF based on the framework - I'd say the effort isn't worth it, just accept it cannot be done.